# Cлово "риелтор"

Tags: орфография, лексика

Как правильно писать: "риелтор" или "риэлтор"? Или, может быть, "риелтер"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно "риелтор". Это неологизм, слово проиходит от английского слова "realty", что, в свою очередь является сокращением от "real estate" - "недвижимое имущество".

Answer (score 2):

Орфографический словарь:

> риелтор, -а

Русское словесное ударение:

> риелтор [иэ]

http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&word=%F0%E8%3F%EB%F2%3F%F0

Answer (score -1):

О как они всё тут решили! "Риелтор" - правильно, я сказал".
В русском языке это заимствование считается неустоявшимся, поэтому ДОПУСТИМЫ все варианты:
риэлтор, риэлтер, риелтор, риелтер и даже реалтор.

Comment: Статья на сайте недвижимости авторитетнее словаря? Хотя и  словарь Кузнецовой дает 4 варианта написания. Но изданный на несколько лет позже орфографический словарь (Институт русского языка), а также словари иностранных слов и словарь ударений дают именно такое написание.  Минус - за пренебрежительное отношение к отвечающим.

Comment: Авторитетнее всего - реальное словоупотребление. В Нацкорпусе - 25 примеров ри**э**лтора и всего 4 - ри**е**лтора. Написание *риэлтор* совпадает с произношением, так и надо писать. Плюс - за реализм.

Comment: В Нацкорпс, увы, не попадают слова, недавно получившие нормативное закрепление. 
Разумеется, и словарь не догма, можно спорить, но не на таком уровне аргументации. Так что полностью присоединяюсь к Ларf.

>Четкого ответа о правописании слова «риэлтор» не могут дать и существующие словари. ***Специалисты агентства недвижимости «Линк» провели свое исследование.***   
    
Это песТня (С).

Наши кухарки провели мастер-класс по управлению государством, не иначе.

Единственное, чего не понял, на какого Лопатина они ссылаются.

Comment: Гугл тоже на запрос "риелтор" дает в основном "риэлтор". Наука-наукой, а народ голосует вывесками!